# Template no encontrao jinja2 flak

Tags: python, linux, flask

tengo un problema con mi flask y este es TenplateNotFound, despues de actualizar Ubuntu me ha dejado de funcionar flask, aqui adjunto imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo app.py es:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates') 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):0
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def template_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

y mi orden de archivos es:

[image: Carpetas]

tengo Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion:
coloquen e app.py en su carpeta app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]